# c# filtering dynamic property names in lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I'm having trouble with poorly named properties:

```
public class Word
{
     public string Alt01 { get;set; }
     public string Alt02 { get;set; }
     public string Alt03 { get;set; }
     public string Alt04 { get;set; }
     public string Alt05 { get;set; }
}
```

This should probably have been one property of the type `List<string>`. But someone else came up with this idea, and I can't change the structure at the moment.

I have a method that returns a lot of `Word` objects. What I would like to do is to filter out each `Word` instance that has a matching string in one or more of the `AltXX` properties.

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach(var word in resultList) //<-- List<Word> 
{
    var alt01 = word.GetType().GetProperty("alt01").GetValue(word, null);
}
```

This would work as my filter if I extend it a bit. But my question is: Is this solvable using lambda expressions?

Comment: is it limited to Alt05 or goes even beyond that?

Comment: the number of Alt## entries can vary per word?  And they are properties?  How the heck did you get a list of dissimilar objects like that?

Comment: @Nevyn Alt01 to Alt15. And as I mentioned earlier, I didn't come up with this idea. Just trying to make the best of the situaation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So we'll start with a simple helper (possibly extension) method since we have a bunch of properties and not a list:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> getAlts(Word word)
{
    yield return word.Alt01;
    yield return word.Alt02;
    yield return word.Alt03;
    yield return word.Alt04;
    yield return word.Alt05;
}
```

You could refactor that to use reflection if it could have N properties instead of exactly five.  God help you if that's really the case for you.  Slap the developer who put you in that position instead of just using a `List` once for me too.

With that, it's not too bad:

```
List<Word> words = new List<Word>();

string searchText = "foo";
var query = words.Where(word => getAlts(word).Any(alt => alt.Contains(searchText)));
```

I want the words `Where` `Any` of the alt's for that word contain the search text.  It reads just like it works.

Comment: He could probably just add it into the class as a method. Like `IEnumerable<string> GetAlts(){/** Code **/}`

Comment: @Romoku Potentially.  I'd like to think that if he has control over the definition of the class he could just refactor it to use a `List`, but I suppose doing so may be too much work.  If he can put it in the class, it certainly belongs there.

Comment: @Servy, your slap now has a candidate. OP has confirmed it's upto Alt15. :)

Comment: @publicgk As long as it's a fixed number, I'd probably just type out the 15.  It's not *that* bad, probably easier to work with than reflection.  If it was 100, or N, based on the runtime type of the class passed in, then you may be forced to use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the class to `List<string>` in a backwards compatible way by creating a helper class.

E.G.

```
class QueryFriendlyWordList
{
    public List<string> Words;

    public QueryFriendlyWordList(Word words)
    {
            Words = new List<string> {words.P1,words.P2, words.P3, words.P4};
    }
}
```

Usage

```
        Word words = new Word {P1 = "abcd", P2 = "abc", P3 = "def", P4 = "qwre"};
        var queryable = new QueryFriendlyWordList(words);
        var result = queryable.Words.Where(w => w.Contains("a"));
```

Static is even easier:

```
static class WordConverter
{       
    public static List<string> Convert(Word words)
    {
            return new List<string> {words.P1,words.P2, words.P3, words.P4};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks clean and simple as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is use reflection one time at the start of your app to build expression trees, which compile into lambdas, then save those lambdas to be re-used.

The price for the slowness of reflection is only paid once, then afterward it's as fast as if you had compiled it from the beginning.

However, it's a pain in the neck to write those expression trees, so if you're not concerned about performance (it's slow, but not THAT slow), then your reflection should be fine.